# TypeError on freebusy call to Google Calendar API v3 using Python apiclient

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I want to get all the freebusy events of my Google Calendar between two given dates. I'm following the [documentation of the freebusy object](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/calendar_v3.freebusy.html).

Basically, I have an index.html with a form that allows to choose two dates. I send those dates to my application (Python Google AppEngine backed).

This is the code, simplified, to make it more readable:

```
CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json')

decorator = oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets(
    CLIENT_SECRETS,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

service = build('calendar', 'v3')

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  @decorator.oauth_required
  def get(self):
    # index.html contains a form that calls my_form
    template = jinja_enviroment.get_template("index.html")
    self.response.out.write(template.render())

class MyRequestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  @decorator.oauth_aware
  def post(self):
    if decorator.has_credentials():

      # time_min and time_max are fetched from form, and processed to make them
      # rfc3339 compliant
      time_min = some_process(self.request.get(time_min))
      time_max = some_process(self.request.get(time_max))

      # Construct freebusy query request's body
      freebusy_query = {
        "timeMin" : time_min,
        "timeMax" : time_max,
        "items" :[
          {
            "id" : my_calendar_id
          }
        ]
      }

      http = decorator.http()
      request = service.freebusy().query(freebusy_query)
      result = request.execute(http=http)
    else:
      # raise error: no user credentials

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),     
    ('/my_form', MyRequestHandler),
    (decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler())
], debug=True)
```

But I get this error in the freebusy call (interesting part of the stack trace):

```
File "/Users/jorge/myapp/oauth2client/appengine.py", line 526, in setup_oauth
    return method(request_handler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jorge/myapp/myapp.py", line 204, in post
    request = service.freebusy().query(freebusy_query)
  TypeError: method() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I've done some research, but I didn't found any running example with calendar v3 and freebusy call on Python. I successfully executed the call in the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.freebusy.query).

If I understood the error, seems that the oauth_aware decorator *filters* in any way all the calls of the code under its control. A callable is passed to the method `OAuthDecorator.oauth_aware` of oauth2client. And this callable is an instance of webapp2.RequestHandler. Like `MyRequestHandler`.

If the user is properly logged, then the oauth_aware method returns a call to desired method, by calling `method(request_handler, *args, **kwargs)`. And here comes the error. A `TypeError`, because `method` is taking more arguments than allowed.

That's my interpretation, but I don't know if I'm right. Should I call `freebusy().query()` in any other way? Does any piece of my analysis really make sense? I'm lost with this...

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `service.freebusy().query(body=freebusy_query)`?

Comment: It works! Should I add the response, giving you the credit, or do you want to post it?

Comment: Good enough. You can always upvote my comment if you want to show love, but it's not so big a deal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [bossylobster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1068170/bossylobster) suggested, the solution was really easy. Just replace this call

```
service.freebusy().query(freebusy_query)
```

With this one

```
service.freebusy().query(body=freebusy_query)
```

Thanks!