# gdata OAuth2 how to work with multiple user's tokens

Tags: refresh, oauth-2.0, token, gdata

## SCENARIO:

I save token in datastore for each app user when grants the access.

I need to create several GData contacts authorized clients in order to
access different user's contacts, i get the tokens for the required users
from datastore and create authorized contacts clients, e.g. copy one user's
contacts to other user's contacts.

## PROBLEM:

The authorized client works as expected and gets the contacts feed of the
user whose token is used, but with the token the token expiry date is also
saved and it expires in an hour or 45 minutes and then it doesnt work anymore,
i read that if the refresh token is there in the token object then token
will automatically get new access token if the short lived access token is
expired but this is not happening.

## Question:

How can i refresh the token after getting it from the datastore if it is
expired, so that i can access user's contacts as long as the user does not
revoke the access?

## CODE :

> ```
> SCOPE = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
> REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8888/mainPage'
> USER_AGENT = 'shared-contacts'
>
> token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(client_id=CLIENT_ID,
>                               client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
>                               scope=SCOPE,
>                               user_agent=USER_AGENT)
>
> class MyEntity(db.Model):
>   userEmail = db.StringProperty()
>     access_token = ObjectProperty()
>
> class ObjectProperty(db.BlobProperty):
>     def validate(self, value):
>         try:
>             result = pickle.dumps(value)
>             return value
>         except pickle.PicklingError, e:
>             return super(ObjectProperty, self).validate(value)
>
>     def get_value_for_datastore(self, model_instance):
>         result = super(ObjectProperty, self).get_value_for_datastore(model_instance)
>         result = pickle.dumps(result)
>         return db.Blob(result)
>
>     def make_value_from_datastore(self, value):
>         try:
>             value = pickle.loads(str(value))
>         except:
>             pass
>         return super(ObjectProperty, self).make_value_from_datastore(value)
>
> class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
>     def get(self):
>         user = users.get_current_user()
>         if user:
>             self.redirect(token.generate_authorize_url(
>                                                   redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI,
>                                                   access_type='offline')
>                                                   )
>         else:
>             self.redirect(users.create_login_url("/"))
>
> class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
>
>     def get(self):
>         # Getting the token from datastore, if token exists for this user then
>       # proceed otherwise get the access token and save in datastore.
>
>       accessToken = Fetch_Access_Token()
>
>         if accessToken:
>             pass
>         else:
>             url = atom.http_core.Uri.parse_uri(self.request.uri)
>             code = url.query
>             code = code['code']
>
>             if 'error' in code:
>                 # User Did Not Grant The Access
>                 pass
>             else:
>                 token_user_email = users.get_current_user().email()
>                 token.GetAccessToken(code)
>                 entity = MyEntity(userEmail=token_user_email, access_token=token)
>                 entity.put()
>
>         self.response.out.write(template.render('index.html',{}))
>
> class RPCMethods():
>     def MoveContacts(self, *args):
>
>       # All tokens except current user
>       shared_group_users = shared_users(skip_current_user)
>
>         contact_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(source=USER_AGENT)
>
>       for sg_user in shared_group_users.itervalues():
>
>           shared_user_token = sg_user[1]
>
>           # PROBLEM OCCURS HERE, IT WORKS FOR ONLY 1 HOUR AND HERE I NEED
>           TO REFRESH THIS TOKEN.
>
>           # For almost an hour i get other user's Data, but after that i
>           get current user's Data.
>
>           shared_user_authorized_client = shared_user_token.authorize(contact_client)
>           shared_group_contact_feed = shared_user_authorized_client.GetContacts()
>
> application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
>                                       ('/', MainHandler),
>                                       ('/mainPage', MainPage),
>                                       ('/rpc', RPCHandler),
>                                       ], debug=True)
> ```

## UPDATE:

## Working Code:

```
shared_user_credentials = StorageByKeyName(CredentialsModel, shared_user_credentials_key, 'credentials').get()

    if shared_user_credentials.access_token_expired == True:
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = shared_user_credentials.authorize(http)
        shared_user_credentials.refresh(http)
```

Comment: How are you storing it in the datastore? What are you executing to get to `atom.http_core.Uri.parse_uri(self.request.uri)`?

Comment: @bossylobster
The token object i get using gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token, i was unable to save it
in the datastore using the provided methods in app engine e.g. ae_save or
datastore CredentialsProperty(), so i searched n found one solution.

Answer to your question was too long for the comment so i have edited the
question and added all the code, please have a look, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So the OAuth 2.0 code is "completely fine", but the way you are obtaining the token the subsequent times you need it is the issue.

In another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942340/get-refresh-token-google-api/10220362#10220362), I mention that the [offline access](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline) portion of the OAuth2.0 docs state:

> When your application receives a refresh token, it is important to
>   store that refresh token for future use. If your application loses the
>   refresh token, it will have to re-prompt the user for consent before
>   obtaining another refresh token. If you need to re-prompt the user for
>   consent, include the `approval_prompt` parameter in the authorization
>   code request, and set the value to `force`.

## SIMPLE FIX:

So when you call `generate_authorize_url`, send `approval_prompt='force'`:

```
self.redirect(token.generate_authorize_url(redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI,
                                           access_type='offline',
                                           approval_prompt='force')
```

You'll notice that `approval_prompt` is already in the [signature](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/gauth.py?r=624d33ad26f2664e8648cd4064ba5dc0a298e6b4#1239) for the `generate_authorize_url` method.

## ACTUAL FIX:

When you are storing your token:

```
token_user_email = users.get_current_user().email()
token.GetAccessToken(code)
entity = MyEntity(userEmail=token_user_email, access_token=token)
```

you know you'll have an entity set for the current user. I'd recommend storing it instead with

```
entity = MyEntity(id=token_user_email, access_token=token).
```

When you make your users go through the OAuth 2.0 flow,

```
user = users.get_current_user()
if user:
    self.redirect(token.generate_authorize_url(
    ...
```

you should first check if there is already a token for the given user:

```
token = MyEntity.get_by_id(user.email())
if token is not None:
    # do something
```

and you should really, **really**, **REALLY**, not use `token` as a global object!

Honestly, there are so many ways to get this wrong and you're probably better off using the `OAuth2Decorator` from `google-api-python-client`.

For some reference on how to combine this decorator with `gdata-python-client`, check out an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981641/gae-enforcing-sign-in-by-app-yaml-python-decorators-or-users-get-current-user/13981710#13981710) I posted on another question.

## PARTING NOTE:

You should use the `ndb` [datastore library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/). Instead of having to write that hideous `ObjectProperty`, you could've simple used `ndb.PickleProperty` with no effort required on your part.

Comment: thanks alot, clicked on 'useful answer' but not enough reputations i have it says :S
i am now trying the oauth flow with decorator using your post "Bridging OAuth 2.0 objects between GData and Discovery".
switched from bd to ndb as well n now i dont even need to save the token because "OAuth2TokenFromCredentials" will have one.
hopefully token this time ill get refreshed because i cant prompt user to grant access on every refresh using "approval_prompt" because ill need to create many contacts client to work with their contacts

Comment: now ill save the credentials object using,

storage = StorageByKeyName(CredentialsModel, user.user_id(), 'credentials'),

storage.put(decorator.credentials)

Comment: the object "Credentials" using decorator after getting it from the datastore, now i am able to refresh it if the access token is expired.
the next problem would be when the refresh token will expire, i have read its valid for 14 days.
updating the question n including the new code, thanks a lot for your help and for one of the best and most useful articles, bridging discovery n gdata.
will disturb you again when i am in trouble again :)